# Compile C code on Mac

Tags: c, compilation

I am trying to compile this interesting program on my mac. The program can make your terminal looks like the one in Matrix movie. Here is the [link](http://asty.org/cmatrix/).

But when I type "make" and press enter in the upzipped source code folder, here is the error:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I am not very familiar with things that need to compile. I know the concept of compilation and c/c++, but have little practical experience.  Is it possible to compile this code on mac? If it is easy, can you tell me how I can compile this code from the above link?

Comment: Could you provide the content of the source code folder ? Did you try to configure?

Comment: seems you have no `Makefile` or your `Makefile` have no running target in it.

Comment: To Samoth, the content file is already provided in the link(end of first paragraph)

Comment: @Rugal, yes. There is two(not one) make file, I don't know how to make necessary change to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the folder of your source code with terminal and type `./configure` and hit enter. Then call `make`.

Answer (score 2):

The package uses the autoconf tools to generate the Makefile(s) required to build the cmatrix application.

In order to generate the makefiles, you need to run the configure script: 
`$ ./configure`

If you have a look at the `INSTALL` file, it should provide some additional information, such as additional arguments that you may need to pass into the configure script for your platform.

Once the configure script has run, you can run make as normal, and it should compile the application.